Creating a Parallel Two-Column Book Template for Codes and Commentary in LaTeX
The American Concrete Institute (ACI) publishes codes like ACI 318-19 in a distinctive parallel two-column format. In this layout, the left column (Code) presents each article, provision, or clause, while the right column (Commentary) provides corresponding commentary. Each section in the Code column is paired with a matching section in the Commentary column, sharing the same title and numbering. Commentary sections are prefixed with "C" to distinguish them (e.g., Code section "1.1 Title" aligns with Commentary section "C1.1 Title") and are excluded from the table of contents—only sections from the Code column appear in the table of contents.
In addition, elements like equations, tables, and figures are independently numbered within each column and reset at the start of each new section. Commentary elements carry a "C" prefix in their numbering as well.
I've noticed that ACI creates these documents using Adobe InDesign. Is it possible to create a similar two-column book template in LaTeX, perhaps with the paracol package? If you've attempted this kind of layout or have insights on how to achieve it in LaTeX, I would greatly appreciate your guidance!
P.S. While I mentioned the paracol package for managing the two-column layout, I would prefer solutions that handle section titles and element numbering using only the basic capabilities of (La)TeX, without relying on additional packages like titlesec.
Update 1. To clarify, my preference is for solutions that handle section and element numbering within LaTeX’s native capabilities, keeping additional packages to a minimum.
Update 2. I’ve attached a screenshot from ACI 318-19 to further illustrate the layout I’m aiming to create. I’m not aiming to replicate the fancy styling shown in the screenshot, just the basic two-column structure and numbering system.



you suggest a third-party package and then say you want to avoid third-party packages. but what have you tried? and what specific problem are you trying to solve right now? if you want a custom-designed class or package to do this, you can find somebody to create one. but not here (and almost certainly not for free.)

Can you please add at least one screenshot? // Yes, paracol has a synchronization command. Did you see the alternatives? https://ctan.org/topic/parallel

@cfr Thanks for the comment! I’m using paracol only for the two-column layout, but I’d like to handle section numbering with basic LaTeX features rather than extra packages like titlesec. Hope that clarifies!

@ms-spo I’ve attached screenshots for clarification. I prefere paracol because it's compatible with xepersian package, which is suitable for creating the document in Persian.

Thank you, that's better to understand now. // If I read it correctly, you already have a solution. If so, can you please downsize a compileable short demo version (and add it) so we can understand your approach and shortcoming? Thank you

When you don't want to rely on packages like titlesec etc. you can e.g.

modify the existing sectioning functionality
write your own

Here I'll show you some basic elements using counters and \addcontentsline. It's very premature, and long time users of (La)TeX may please forgive my naivity. I refer to The Latex Companion, chapter "2.2 Section commands", pages 24 + 49 in 2nd Edition / pages 34 + 55 in 3rd Edition. Basic functions you'll need:

dependent counters
counter representations
adding to content list

Adding colors, bars, fonts etc. are secondary tasks.

Dependent counters
Defined:
\newcounter{ca}
\newcounter{cb}[ca]

Combined, as you may need to label a "section":
\newcommand\cnumb{\theca.\thecb}

Tested/demonstrated: hi \cnumb
Basic functions needed (at least)
In running text you'll see:

incrementing counters ca or cb
with appropriate reset to 0 (and a missing increment so far)
output macro \cnumb
entry into toc (very immature)

\stepcounter{ca} \cnumb \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\cnumb\ Start}

Still a lot of work to do, like

complying with the correct hierarchie, resets etc.
layout considerations
etc.
and certainly experienced users will have more to add

But: in principle you can now construct such entries and presentations:

It will be quite a road to travel, though ... not to mention Quality Assurance of your code/package ...

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{ca}
\newcounter{cb}[ca]

\newcommand\cnumb{\theca.\thecb}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

hi \cnumb

\stepcounter{ca} \cnumb \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\cnumb\ Start}

\stepcounter{ca} \cnumb \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\cnumb\ Next}
\newpage

\stepcounter{cb} \cnumb \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\cnumb\ Next page}

\stepcounter{cb} \cnumb

\stepcounter{ca} \cnumb
\end{document}


Thank you for your contribution! Please take a look at my answer for further discussion.

Thank you. // Sorry, you lost me at "ChatGPT" ... Bye

Thank you for your contributions so far! I wish you the best of luck in your future projects. If you have any questions later, feel free to reach out.

I created a LaTeX template, with help from ChatGPT, for a parallel two-column book layout with aligned code and commentary. This template is intended to allow code sections to appear alongside commentary explanations in a synchronized format. However, the template currently has some issues:
There are two possible directions forward:

Fix the current bugs in the existing template.
Rebuild the template from scratch, using an alternative approach.

Below is an outline of the current solution, including package imports, style customizations, and the code required to enable the parallel column layout. All code is set up in the preamble.
The full code of the template is provided at the end.
Step-by-Step Template Setup
1. Import Packages and Redefine Chapter Heading Styles
We begin by importing necessary packages and customizing chapter headings to ensure centered alignment.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks]{hyperref}

% --- Redefine chapter title style
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}% default: 50 (space before chapter title)
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont % make centered
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter\space% removed: \@chapapp\space 
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak % Default: \Huge
    \vskip 28\p@ % default: 40 (space after the chapter title)
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}% default: 50 (space before chapter title)
  {\parindent \z@ \centering % make centered
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 28\p@ % default: 40 (space after the chapter title)
  }}
\makeatother

2. Define Custom Counters
Separate counters are defined to handle numbering for sections, equations, tables, and figures in each column (Code and Commentary).
% --- Define counters for headings
\newcounter{codesection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thecodesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{codesection}}

\newcounter{codesubsection}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodesubsection}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codesubsection}}

\newcounter{codesubsubsection}[codesubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecodesubsubsection}{\thecodesubsection-\arabic{codesubsubsection}}

\newcounter{codeparagraph}[codesubsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecodeparagraph}{\alph{codeparagraph})}

\newcounter{cmtysection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysection}{C\thechapter-\arabic{cmtysection}}

\newcounter{cmtysubsection}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysubsection}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtysubsection}}

\newcounter{cmtysubsubsection}[cmtysubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysubsubsection}{\thecmtysubsection-\arabic{cmtysubsubsection}}

\newcounter{cmtyparagraph}[cmtysubsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyparagraph}{C\alph{cmtyparagraph})}

% --- Define custom counters for floats in commentary column
\newcounter{codeequation}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodeequation}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codeequation}}

\newcounter{codetable}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodetable}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codetable}}

\newcounter{codefigure}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodefigure}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codefigure}}

\newcounter{cmtyequation}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyequation}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtyequation}}

\newcounter{cmtytable}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtytable}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtytable}}

\newcounter{cmtyfigure}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyfigure}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtyfigure}}


3. Define Column-Tracking Flags
Flags track which column is active, allowing sectioning commands to adapt to each column’s counter system.
\newif\ifincode
\incodetrue % Code column is active by default
\newif\ifincommentary
\incommentaryfalse % Commentary column is inactive by default

% --- Commands to switch columns and update numbering
\newcommand{\codetext}{
  \incommentaryfalse
  \incodetrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thecodesection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thecodesubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thecodesubsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thecodeparagraph}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thecodeequation}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thecodetable}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thecodefigure}
}

\newcommand{\commentarytext}{
  \incodefalse
  \incommentarytrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thecmtysection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thecmtysubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thecmtysubsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thecmtyparagraph}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thecmtyequation}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thecmtytable}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thecmtyfigure}
}

4. Patch Environments to Auto-Increment Counters
Environment patches ensure that elements like equations, tables, and figures increment automatically in the correct column.
% --- Patch environments to increment counters when used
\preto\equation{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codeequation}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyequation}
  \fi
}

\preto\gather{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codeequation}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyequation}
  \fi
}

\preto\table{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codetable}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtytable}
  \fi
}

\preto\figure{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codefigure}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyfigure}
  \fi
}


5. Define Custom Environments
Custom environments for parallel clause layouts and single-column code/commentary sections.
\newenvironment{clause}[4]{% #1: heading; #2: title; #3: code; #4: commentary
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\codetext
\refstepcounter{code#1}
\csname #1\endcsname *{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
#3
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\commentarytext
\refstepcounter{cmty#1}
\csname #1\endcsname *{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
#4
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
}{}

% --- Define parallel text
\newenvironment{paratext}[2]{% #1: code; #2: commentary
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\codetext
#1
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\commentarytext
#2
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
}{}

% --- Define single column code
\newenvironment{widecode}{\codetext}{}

% --- Define single column commentary
\newenvironment{widecmty}{\commentarytext}{}

Current Issues

Commentary Section Reset: The cmtysection counter does not reset with each new chapter.
Wide (Big) Element Numbering: Wide elements (like those in widecmty) do not number correctly.
Multi-line Equation Numbering: Multi-line environments such as gather should ideally increment counters for each line but currently do not.

Full Code of the Template
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE LAYOUT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\addtolength{\marginparsep}{-7pt}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{-115pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{+108pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-28pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-79pt}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-23pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{+48pt}

\addtolength{\headheight}{+8pt}


% --- Create [This page intetionally left blank.]

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}~\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER CONFIGURATIONS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,amsbsy,amsopn,amstext}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mhsetup,mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx} \sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hypcap=true,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}


% --- Other packages
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for modifying space before chapter title
\usepackage{upgreek} % for upgreek letters
\usepackage{paracol} % for parallel text


% --- Make sure “hyperref” and “algorithm2e” come last of your loaded packages.
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks]{hyperref}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING STYLES SETTINGS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% --- Redefine chapter title style
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}% default: 50 (space before chapter title)
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont % make centered
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter\space% removed: \@chapapp\space 
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak % Default: \Huge
    \vskip 28\p@ % default: 40 (space after the chapter title)
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}% default: 50 (space before chapter title)
  {\parindent \z@ \centering % make centered
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 28\p@ % default: 40 (space after the chapter title)
  }}
\makeatother



% Controls printing of section heading numbers at any depth > {level},
% where chapter is level 0 in books and section is level 0 in articles.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


% --- Redefine heading title style
\makeatletter
% space between number and title (default is 1em)
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname \hspace{0.5em}}
% style of section
\def\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
    }
% style of subsection
\def\subsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {-1.5ex \@plus -.2ex}% default: 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
    }
% style of subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{%
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {-1.5ex \@plus -.2ex}% default: 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
    }
% style of paragraph
\def\paragraph{%
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1ex}% default: -1em
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
    }
\makeatother


% --- Define counters for headings numbering
\newcounter{codesection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thecodesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{codesection}}

\newcounter{codesubsection}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodesubsection}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codesubsection}}

\newcounter{codesubsubsection}[codesubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecodesubsubsection}{\thecodesubsection-\arabic{codesubsubsection}}

\newcounter{codeparagraph}[codesubsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecodeparagraph}{\alph{codeparagraph})}

\newcounter{cmtysection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysection}{C\thechapter-\arabic{cmtysection}}

\newcounter{cmtysubsection}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysubsection}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtysubsection}}

\newcounter{cmtysubsubsection}[cmtysubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtysubsubsection}{\thecmtysubsection-\arabic{cmtysubsubsection}}

\newcounter{cmtyparagraph}[cmtysubsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyparagraph}{C\alph{cmtyparagraph})}


% --- Define custom counters for floats in commentary column
\newcounter{codeequation}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodeequation}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codeequation}}

\newcounter{codetable}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodetable}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codetable}}

\newcounter{codefigure}[codesection]
\renewcommand{\thecodefigure}{\thecodesection-\arabic{codefigure}}


\newcounter{cmtyequation}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyequation}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtyequation}}

\newcounter{cmtytable}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtytable}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtytable}}

\newcounter{cmtyfigure}[cmtysection]
\renewcommand{\thecmtyfigure}{\thecmtysection-\arabic{cmtyfigure}}


% --- Define a flag to know where is now
\newif\ifincode
\incodetrue % set incode true
\newif\ifincommentary
\incommentaryfalse % set incommentary false


% --- Redefine switching columns to also change counters
\newcommand{\codetext}{
  \incommentaryfalse
  \incodetrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thecodesection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thecodesubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thecodesubsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thecodeparagraph}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thecodeequation}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thecodetable}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thecodefigure}
}

\newcommand{\commentarytext}{
  \incodefalse
  \incommentarytrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thecmtysection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thecmtysubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thecmtysubsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thecmtyparagraph}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thecmtyequation}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thecmtytable}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thecmtyfigure}
}


% --- Patch the environments to automatically increment the counters when used
\preto\equation{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codeequation}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyequation}
  \fi
}

\preto\gather{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codeequation}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyequation}
  \fi
}

\preto\table{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codetable}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtytable}
  \fi
}

\preto\figure{%
  \ifincode
    \refstepcounter{codefigure}
  \fi
  \ifincommentary
    \refstepcounter{cmtyfigure}
  \fi
}


% --- Define clause environment
\newenvironment{clause}[4]{% #1: heading; #2: title; #3: code; #4: commentary
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\codetext
\refstepcounter{code#1}
\csname #1\endcsname *{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
#3
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\commentarytext
\refstepcounter{cmty#1}
\csname #1\endcsname *{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25em} #2}
#4
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
}{}


% --- Define parallel text
\newenvironment{paratext}[2]{% #1: code; #2: commentary
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\codetext
#1
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\commentarytext
#2
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
}{}


% --- Define single column code
\newenvironment{widecode}{\codetext}{}


% --- Define single column commentary
\newenvironment{widecmty}{\commentarytext}{}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SETTINGS AND CONFIGURATIONS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt minus 2pt}

% The horizontal space between columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{\parindent}


% --- Setting for ToC

% Controls displaying of section heading numbers in table of content
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% Fix bug in ToC
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\hspace{1ex}}



% --- Define new commands for math mode
\newcommand{\mdot}{ \ensuremath{{\cdot}} }
\newcommand{\ud}{ \ensuremath{\, \mathrm{d}} }





%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   START OF DOCUMNENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\frontmatter \pagestyle{empty}

%**************************************************
%   Titlepage

\title{Title of Manuscript}
\author{John Doe}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Titlepage}{bkm:titlepage}
\maketitle
%**************************************************

\cleardoublepage

%**************************************************
%   Tables of contents.
\pagestyle{plain}

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{bkm:tableofcontents}
\tableofcontents \cleardoublepage

\listoftables \cleardoublepage

\listoffigures \cleardoublepage
%**************************************************


\mainmatter \pagestyle{headings}
%**************************************************
%   Chapters
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{clause}{section}{Section Title}
{% Code
Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus velit himenaeos malesuada conubia nunc urna nostra.
\begin{equation}
ax^2 + bx + c = 0
\end{equation}

}{% Commentary
Suscipit urna primis dolor urna tincidunt ad blandit. Felis vestibulum duis hac semper egestas erat luctus. Maximus molestie gravida donec augue leo primis. Montes primis nibh netus pharetra lacus maecenas. In leo sollicitudin; feugiat sagittis ullamcorper felis. Ultrices lacinia tempor orci eros praesent montes nullam.
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\Delta = b^2 - 4ac
\end{equation}
}
\end{clause}


\begin{widecode}
\begin{equation}
Z = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{E_i}{k_B T}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} = \exp\left(-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \ud x
\end{equation}
\end{widecode}


\begin{widecmty}
\begin{equation}
Z = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{E_i}{k_B T}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} = \exp\left(-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \ud x
\end{equation}
\end{widecmty}


\begin{clause}{section}{Section Title}
{% Code
Dictum platea euismod facilisi fermentum quis neque duis class. Tincidunt enim accumsan montes nisi vehicula rhoncus. Dictum suspendisse elementum cras congue maecenas scelerisque class ridiculus neque? Laoreet in nostra litora in hendrerit mi per ultrices placerat.

\begin{table}[H] \centering
\caption{A sample table in code column}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\
\midrule
Cell 1 & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \\
Cell 5 & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8 \\
Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

}{% Commentary
Nulla aenean nibh tempus blandit nisl montes aliquam sollicitudin. Dapibus curae maecenas sapien ullamcorper eget ridiculus lectus blandit. Nascetur dui at sagittis molestie etiam vulputate.

\begin{table}[H] \centering
\caption{A sample table in commentary column}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\
\midrule
Cell 1 & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \\
Cell 5 & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8 \\
Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{clause}


\begin{paratext}
{% Code
\begin{table}[H] \centering
\caption{Another sample table in code column}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\
\midrule
Cell 1 & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \\
Cell 5 & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8 \\
Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

}{% Commentary
\begin{table}[H] \centering
\caption{Another sample table in commentary column}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\
\midrule
Cell 1 & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \\
Cell 5 & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8 \\
Cell 9 & Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{paratext}


\begin{widecode}
\begin{table}[H] 
\centering
\caption{A wide (big) table in code}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 & Header 5 & Header 6 & Header 7 & Header 8 & Header 9 \\
\midrule
Cell 1  & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4  & Cell 5  & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8  & Cell 9  \\
Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 & Cell 13 & Cell 14 & Cell 15 & Cell 16 & Cell 17 & Cell 18 \\
Cell 19 & Cell 20 & Cell 21 & Cell 22 & Cell 23 & Cell 24 & Cell 25 & Cell 26 & Cell 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{widecode}


\begin{widecmty}
\begin{table}[H] 
\centering
\caption{A wide (big) table in commentary}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 & Header 5 & Header 6 & Header 7 & Header 8 & Header 9 \\
\midrule
Cell 1  & Cell 2  & Cell 3  & Cell 4  & Cell 5  & Cell 6  & Cell 7  & Cell 8  & Cell 9  \\
Cell 10 & Cell 11 & Cell 12 & Cell 13 & Cell 14 & Cell 15 & Cell 16 & Cell 17 & Cell 18 \\
Cell 19 & Cell 20 & Cell 21 & Cell 22 & Cell 23 & Cell 24 & Cell 25 & Cell 26 & Cell 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{widecmty}


\begin{clause}{section}{Section Title}
{% Code
Parturient torquent fringilla feugiat cubilia mus purus. Eu dignissim ut pellentesque tristique etiam gravida condimentum luctus consequat.
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\caption{A sample figure in code}
\end{figure}

}{% Commentary
Senectus venenatis scelerisque sollicitudin vulputate hac dictum luctus eu. Tempor ad curae ridiculus mauris hendrerit erat penatibus inceptos posuere. Suspendisse sed donec cubilia montes, justo semper non donec.
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-B}
\caption{A sample figure in commentary}
\end{figure}
}
\end{clause}


\begin{paratext}
{% Code
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\caption{Another sample figure in code}
\end{figure}

}{% Commentary
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-B}
\caption{Another sample figure in commentary}
\end{figure}
}
\end{paratext}


\begin{widecode}
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\caption{A wide (big) figure in code}
\end{figure}
\end{widecode}


\begin{widecmty}
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-B}
\caption{A wide (big) figure in commentary}
\end{figure}
\end{widecmty}










\chapter{Dolor Sit Amet}


\begin{clause}{section}{Section Title}
{% Code
Leo nullam gravida eget condimentum et blandit. Quis velit hac augue felis litora. Odio laoreet justo mus proin maecenas gravida.
\begin{equation}
z = a + i b
\end{equation}

}{% Commentary
Mus felis mauris accumsan elementum etiam scelerisque. Leo et torquent rhoncus, nostra parturient porttitor fringilla adipiscing. Egestas pellentesque gravida conubia inceptos lobortis. Nullam egestas luctus in fames commodo donec facilisi fringilla. Nibh at arcu mus nec praesent accumsan.
\begin{equation}
z = r(\cos\ \theta + i\sin\ \theta)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{gather}
r = |z| = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\\
a = r\cos\ \theta\\
b = r\sin\ \theta
\end{gather}
}
\end{clause}



\begin{clause}{subsection}{Subsection Title}
{% Code
Tempor venenatis eros non elit quis commodo. Porta dapibus vel tempus, tincidunt nunc ante. Curabitur nec eleifend magna nullam; blandit sed quam facilisis arcu. Risus aliquet vel pulvinar eget donec. Urna ligula aptent vivamus aptent montes!

}{% Commentary
Bibendum sagittis neque porttitor neque sagittis nulla nec mauris. Placerat etiam leo eleifend; suspendisse lectus semper justo.
}
\end{clause}



\begin{clause}{subsubsection}{Subsubsection Title}
{% Code
Vehicula nulla nisi eu fermentum ut. Curabitur viverra posuere risus parturient scelerisque blandit cubilia.

}{% Commentary
Faucibus tempor platea dui condimentum urna mollis iaculis scelerisque. Conubia aenean fusce auctor; massa consequat facilisi magna finibus interdum. Hac accumsan quis augue tempor erat malesuada efficitur elementum. Sollicitudin fames lorem aliquam per turpis quam facilisi vel. Curabitur diam integer sagittis; lorem auctor metus eget?
}
\end{clause}



\begin{clause}{paragraph}{Paragraph Title}
{% Code
Nibh curae quisque dolor nullam hac conubia. Euismod justo nisi libero vestibulum neque. Imperdiet conubia dictumst id aptent neque bibendum a.

}{% Commentary
Accumsan urna odio ridiculus habitant luctus dui nulla. Erat luctus ad aliquam; porttitor conubia sed duis. Integer maecenas vitae ridiculus eleifend, magna conubia dolor.
}
\end{clause}

%
%**************************************************



%**************************************************
%   Appendixes
\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{A\arabic{chapter}}

\chapter{Cubilia Mus Lobortis}

\begin{clause}{section}{Section Title}
{% Code
Taciti pellentesque leo torquent metus. Faucibus nibh efficitur faucibus ornare in. Ex quis ultricies pharetra mollis suscipit facilisi. Porta non mus maximus massa mus vestibulum accumsan pulvinar.

}{% Commentary
Urna fames torquent sit egestas sagittis leo dis nam placerat. Molestie cubilia hendrerit taciti dictumst nibh orci venenatis tempor vivamus. Cras lectus elementum congue hendrerit lacinia. Nam eget mollis viverra, facilisi massa at proin.
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
}
\end{clause}
%
%**************************************************

\backmatter \pagestyle{empty}



\end{document}

